# SCCM Collection Query to check Outlook.exe on Win 7 x86 and x64

Tags: sql, wmi, sccm

I need to use a single collection to target both win7(x86) and win7(x64) builds to check if Outlook.exe is installed under program files, but the problem is under Win7(x86) Install directory is under “C:\Program Files\” and Win7(x64) Install directory is under “C:\Program Files(x86)\” hence I can’t target using one collection

The script I’m using below targets on Win7(x86) but not Win7(x64) 
Can someone please help with a WMI query where I can target both Win7(x86) and (x64) to check if Outlook.exe is installed

“SELECT SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client , SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name, SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID, SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FilePath, SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileName,  SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileVersion FROM SMS_R_System INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile ON SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId WHERE SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FilePath LIKE "%Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\" AND SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileName = " WINWORD.EXE" AND SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileVersion LIKE "14.%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, try this:

```
SELECT 
SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client , SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name, SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,
SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FilePath, SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileName,
SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileVersion FROM SMS_R_System 
INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile ON 
SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId 
WHERE 
(
   SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FilePath LIKE "%Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\" 
   OR 
   SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FilePath LIKE "%Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\"
) AND SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileName = "outlook.exe"
```

That'll include both folders. I've also replaced your "WINWORD.EXE" with "outlook.exe" and removed the FileVersion check as I'd say it's safe to assume it's version 14 if it's in the "Office14" folder.